# Java Spring - The HttpClient assigns an extra field when serializing a ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, serialization, httprequest, httpresponse

In short the problem is I have the following body for the HttpResponse:

```
{"mammalList":[{"id":11,"details":{"id":3,"name":"Kangaroo","description":"Example",
"image":null},"age":40,"hasHooves":true,"hasPlacenta":false,"name":"Kangaroo"}]}
```

### At the end, there is another field ***"name":"Kangaroo"***

a Mammal is:
`Mammal(Long id, Details details, int age, boolean hasHooves, boolean hasPlacenta)`
with Details being `Details(Long id, String name, String description, String image)`

Say I have a Get mapping `animals/all/mammals`

I have a get method, which first creates an HttpRequest

```
public static <E> E get(String path, Class<E> responseType) {
        // Build HTTP request
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(host + "/" + path))
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").GET().build();
```

then tries to get a response

```
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

/* this is the client - private static final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient(); */

Using a bean and annotations, I get to the method connected to `animals/all/mammals`
and at the end of the method return the following:

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MammalResponse(responseList));
```

(MammalResponse is a class containing only List of Mammal, constructors, getter and setter)

The debugger at the end of the method is showing the following: (which is the expected)

```
responseList = {ArrayList@10790}  size = 1
 0 = {Mammal@10792} 
  age = 40
  hasHooves = true
  hasPlacenta = false
  id = {Long@10793} 11
  details = {Details@10794} 
   id = {Long@10795} 3
   name = "Kangaroo"
   description = "Example"
   image = null
```

The problem is, on when I pass onto the next line of the *get* method, I have the following body for the HttpResponse:

```
{"mammalList":[{"id":11,"details":{"id":3,"name":"Kangaroo","description":"Example",
"image":null},"age":40,"hasHooves":true,"hasPlacenta":false,"name":"Kangaroo"}]}
```

At the end, there is another field ***"name":"Kangaroo"***
the Mammal object doesn't have a name attribute, so it can't be deserialised and everything goes downhill.

### Any idea why it adds that extra attribute at the end of the serialised Mammal string and how I can stop that from happening?

Edit: if I add more Mammals into the database, each is then in the mammalList with the `name` from its Details object put in the end as well.

Comment: Could you show us Mamal and Details Object ? I would like to see if htey are entities and if they have any mapping relation

Comment: do you have a getter on the mamal class , something like 'getName()'  - if yes, that may be the cause

Comment: @ŢîganIon Yes! That fixed it, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ţîgan Ion it's fixed!

I had a getName() method in Mammal and that was the reason the name was put twice. When I commented it out, getting a Mammal from the database works as expected.

Again, thanks to @Ţîgan Ion. If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your description on "which service" you are calling to get that HTTPResponse is far from complete. Is it your own service?

In any case, a quick-fix is to annotate your Mammal class with @JsonIgnoreProperties.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

@JsonIgnoreProperties
class { ... }
```

With that annotation, unknown fields won't make your program go "downhill" anymore.